# Django shell inside Emacs showing escape characters

Tags: python, django, shell, emacs

I'm having trouble using the manage.py shell inside Emacs. I get something like this:

```
Python 3.4.3 (default, Nov 17 2016, 01:08:31) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 5.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

[J[?7h[?12l[?25h[?2004l
[?12l[?25h
```

And every time I press enter I get these escape character in the beginning  of the line. The shell actually still works, but it is very unpleasant.
I think it is an encoding error of some kind, but I have no idea how to fix it.

I'm using Emacs 24.3.1, and use the [django-python package](https://github.com/fgallina/python-django.el) to run the shell inside Emacs.

I'm kind of a newbie to all this, sorry if the question is not properly put.

Thanks

Comment: it is not encoding error but codes which set color text in normal terminal.

Comment: Hi, it's doable. Maybe with [this wiki](http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Shell#Fix.2C_add_colors_and_highlight_text) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was answered on the Emacs stackexchange website: [Weird shell output when using IPython 5](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/24572)

The short story is that IPython switched to using prompt_toolkit which is incompatible with the Emacs shell. Add the `--simple-prompt` argument to switch to an emacs-compatible prompt. This solves the problem for me in Emacs 24 and IPython 6.

You could add this to your .emacs file:

`(setq python-shell-interpreter-args "--simple-prompt")`

Or in Emacs, do:

<kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> customize-group <kbd>RET</kbd> python <kbd>RET</kbd>

and then add `--simple-prompt` to "Python Shell Interpreter Args".

I experimented with the `--color` argument but it doesn't seem to affect the colors displayed by emacs.

Comment: Thanks, I had found the link you posted but forgot to post it here for others with similar issues. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

It is probably not encoding error but codes which `IPython` uses to set color text.

Normally you could do

```
ipython --colors=noColor
```

to run `IPython` without colors.

But I don't know how to do it in this extension.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind as I continue look for solutions.